# Gifts for teachers at private schools?

Tags: primary-schooler, school, teacher

How typical is it for parents to give end-of-school-year gifts to teachers at a private school?

If it is usual or frequent, what types of gifts and how expensive?

(My 6 yo has 4 teachers for his kindergarden class.)

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27996/9327

Comment: Nicer than a bunch of small gifts would be for the parents to contribute to a single gift from the class.

Comment: Sorry, asking "how typical is it" is off-topic IMHO - it's highly localized (depends on culture, situation etc.), and also a poll-type question. For general information on handling gifts to teachers, it's a duplicate of the question linked.

Comment: I was a teacher in a classroom with sometimes 6 adults, (2 teachers, 4 ed assistants). The first day of school we sent home a request for no gifts. **IF** they wanted to do something, there was a list of classroom wants and needs and the trip fund was always in need of a boost as wheelchair transportation was extra expensive. So in primary school -- I'd give a gift to the classroom at the start of term(s) and a thank you note at the end. **If** school policy allows for home baking -- make something for all the staff of the school or everyone in the classroom. Your effort is most meaningful.

Comment: @anongoodnurse  I appreciate all the SE links that you and others provided.  I find it difficult to find answers using the SE search tool. The suggested questions that appeared when I entered the question were not relevant.

Comment: @ZaydeinNY Is this a device-related problem? My tablet is useless with links, so I often cannot follow them or find my place here when I do. My PC manages easily by right clicking and opening the link in a new tab.

Comment: @Willow  I am using a desktop.

Comment: @ZaydeinNY so is there something we can do to help you learn the tools?

Comment: @Willow  I just look at the suggested questions providedd by SE when I start to write a new question.  Is there a  better way?

Comment: You can read them, not just look at the titles/questions. I am not trying to be rude -- but in the beginning that is what I did  and the system doesn't really like duplicates and the members of the community are sticklers about it. In this question, I happen to be the one who asked the 'original'.  Those answers got me thinking and helped. So, you read the answers and either change your question to make it different, or take one as your info, and maybe comment as well. You'll get used to SE -- I did.